# nova-compute for compute node in openstack not working No DB access allowed in nova-compute

Tags: openstack-nova

I have followed this guide https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/yoga/install/compute-install-ubuntu.html the configuration i have is

```
$ sudo egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/nova/nova.conf
[DEFAULT]
log_dir = /var/log/nova
lock_path = /var/lock/nova
state_path = /var/lib/nova
my_ip = 10.0.0.132 
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:openstack@controller1
[api]
auth_strategy = keystone
[api_database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://nova:NOVA_DBPASS@controller1/nova_api
[barbican]
[barbican_service_user]
[cache]
[cinder]
[compute]
[conductor]
[console]
[consoleauth]
[cors]
[cyborg]
[database]
[devices]
[ephemeral_storage_encryption]
[filter_scheduler]
[glance]
api_servers = http://controller1:9292
[guestfs]
[healthcheck]
[hyperv]
[image_cache]
[ironic]
[key_manager]
[keystone]
[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://controller1:5000/
auth_url = http://controller1:5000/
memcached_servers = controller1:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = Default
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
username = nova
password = nova
[libvirt]
[metrics]
[mks]
[neutron]
auth_url = http://controller1:5000
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
region_name = RegionOne
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = neutron
[notifications]
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/nova/tmp
[oslo_messaging_amqp]
[oslo_messaging_kafka]
[oslo_messaging_notifications]
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:openstack@controller1
[oslo_messaging_rabbit]
[oslo_middleware]
[oslo_policy]
[oslo_reports]
[pci]
[placement]
region_name = RegionOne
project_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
auth_type = password
user_domain_name = Default
auth_url = http://controller1:5000/v3
username = placement
password = placement
[powervm]
[privsep]
[profiler]
[quota]
[rdp]
[remote_debug]
[scheduler]
discover_hosts_in_cells_interval = 300
[serial_console]
[service_user]
[spice]
[upgrade_levels]
[vault]
[vendordata_dynamic_auth]
[vmware]
[vnc]
enabled = true
server_listen = 0.0.0.0
server_proxyclient_address = $my_ip
novncproxy_base_url = http://controller1:6080/vnc_auto.html
[workarounds]
[wsgi]
[zvm]
[cells]
enable = False
[os_region_name]
openstack =
```

When I restart nova compute i get the following error

```
ERROR nova.db.main.api [req-36ce098e-300c-4e92-9cd7-e729c1387662 - - - - -] No DB access allowed in nova-compute:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eventlet/greenthread.py", line 221, in main
    result = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/utils.py", line 656, in context_wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/context.py", line 422, in gather_result
    result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/db/main/api.py", line 162, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/objects/service.py", line 511, in _db_service_get_minimum_version
    return db.service_get_minimum_version(context, binaries)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/db/main/api.py", line 221, in wrapper
    _check_db_access()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/nova/db/main/api.py", line 171, in _check_db_access
    stacktrace = ''.join(traceback.format_stack())

2022-11-24 12:06:25.416 179908 WARNING nova.objects.service [req-36ce098e-300c-4e92-9cd7-e729c1387662 - - - - -] Failed to get minimum service version for cell 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
2022-11-24 12:06:25.417 179908 WARNING nova.objects.service [req-36ce098e-300c-4e92-9cd7-e729c1387662 - - - - -] Failed to get minimum service version for cell 17f04b31-b1cf-4145-bffe-a6a340759791
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is unrelated to the issue. Just remove [api_database]connection line on compute node.